# how can we update single state on two tab change in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Please help me for this .whole class code I have shared .
In this code there are two tabs ,
In first tab I am getting value from array and getting sum of T"ransactionAmount" and maping .All these values I am passing in state sum .
Now In second tab there is one input field where I have to wite any number .
Condition : - when I am on tab first then sum on value should disply in below button  and when I go to second tab than whatever value I enter that only come in state sum.
this sum value I am getting in below button . 
Basically there is one state sum where I am updating value on tab change .But in first tab value is coming fine but I am going to second tab and entering tha vale ,then its coming with first tabe value .
Below link is refrence for my ui and screenshot for details .
Please help.
First tabe pic
[image: second tab value]

https://xd.adobe.com/view/d733da48-5d0c-47ca-7ded-6fc8f0f609cf-a102/screen/37cb15c6-b56a-4b98-8612-e9b86d0dd34c/Android-Mobile-147/?fullscreen

```
    // Below is array value 
   financialTransactionDetail: Array(3)
    0:
    AdjustedAmount: "0"
    NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
    TransactionAmount: 1050
    1:
    AdjustedAmount: "0"
    NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
    TransactionAmount: 1050

    2:
    AdjustedAmount: "0"
    NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
    Status: "Unpaid"
    TransactionAmount: 1050

    class PaymentsInvoice extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { navigation,invoiceDetailsinfo } = this.props;
        const{financialTransactionDetail} = invoiceDetailsinfo;
        this.state = {
          title: 'Payments against invoice',
          icon: 'sim',
          mobile:navigation.state.params.customer.service.serviceNumber,
          checked: financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.map(() => true),
          sum:0,
        }
      }

      handleChange(index){
        let newChecked = this.state.checked;
        newChecked[index] = !newChecked[index];
        this.setState({checked: newChecked})
      }

      handleChangeSum = (sumValue) => {
        this.setState({
          sum: parseInt(sumValue)
        });
      }

      render() {
        let { title, icon, mobile,invoice_specific,sum } = this.state;
        const { navigation,invoiceDetailsinfo } = this.props;
        const{financialTransactionDetail} = invoiceDetailsinfo;

        this.state.checked.map((value, index) => { 
          if(value) {
            sum += financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail[index].TransactionAmount; 
          } 
        });
        return (
          <View style={styles.imgBG}>
            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                  <Header title={title} icon={icon} subtitle={mobile} navigation={navigation} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.dataContainer}>
                    <Tabs >
                      <Tab heading="INVOICE SPECIFIC"  tabLabel="SPECIFIC">
                      { !_.isEmpty(financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail) && financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.map(
                        (data, index) => {
                          const formatedate = data.DueDate;
                          const formateDate = formatedate.split(' ')[0];
                          return(
                            <View key={index} style={{flexDirection:'row', padding:10, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between',backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>

                          <View style={{paddingRight:10, marginRight:10}}>
                          <CheckBox style={styles.checkBox} color="#00678f" checked={this.state.checked[index]} onPress={() =>this.handleChange(index)}/>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1, padding:10, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:3}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
                              {!this.state.checked[index] && <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{paddingBottom:10, paddingRight:5}}/>}
                              <SmallText text={`Due by ${(formateDate)}`} style={{paddingBottom:10}}/>
                            </View>
                            {this.state.checked[index] && 
                            <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                              </RegularText>
                            }
                          </View>
                        </View>
                          )
                        }
                      )
                      }

                      </Tab>
                      <Tab heading="AD-HOC" tabLabel="AD-HOC">
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'column', padding:10,  backgroundColor:'#fff', minHeight:deviceHeight }}>
                          <RegularText text="Enter Specific Amount to pay" style={{paddingBottom:5}} textColor="#959595"/>
                          <View>
                            <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                              <Input
                                  autoFocus={true}
                                  onPress={() => this.handleChange('sumValue')}
                                  onChangeText={(sumValue) => this.handleChangeSum(sumValue)}
                                />
                            </Item>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </View>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={{bottom:0,position:'absolute', width: '100%'}}>
              <Button full onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('PaymentOptionsContainer',sum)}>
                <Text>Receive Payment ({sum})</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>

          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    export default PaymentsInvoice;
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use single source of truth i-e include the state in parent component , So when the parent component re renders it gets the value from its own state and pass it on to the child component .